# ¿Como cargar una clase (.cs) mediante su ruta en c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Se que con reflection se puede lograr hacer por medio de la ruta del .DLL del proyecto

```
Assembly proyecto = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Proyecto.dll");
Type tipo = proyecto.GetType("Proyecto.NombreDeLaClase");
object instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo);
```

pero lo que quisiera saber es de si puedo cargar y obtener la información de la clase mediante la ruta del archivo. Por ejemplo:

```
object instancia = Activator.CreateInstance("C:\rutacompleta\clase.cs");
```

Comment: probaste con Activator.CreateInstanceFrom()?

Comment: No funciona de esa manera, Activator.CreateInstanceFrom() recibe dos parametros, uno es la ruta del .dll y otro es el tipo de la clase, es lo mismo que publique, pero gracias por responder.